# Trigger to insert values from Table C into tableB after insert On Table A

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in mysql that updates Table B with values from Table C, after a new record is inserted into Table A. I've tried a few variations of the code below, but can't get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 delimiter //
 CREATE TRIGGER updateC AFTER Insert ON Table A
       FOR EACH ROW in TableB
       BEGIN
           IF TableB.Group = 1 THEN
               Insert into TableC(inserthere) values (TableB.AddThis);
           END IF;
       END;//
delimiter ;
```

> Table A includes the fields ProjectID | TaskGroup.
>
> Table B includes the fields ID | DefaultTask | TaskGroup.
>
> Table C includes the fields ID | ProjectID | DefaultTask.
>
> When a new ProjectID & TaskGroup are added to table A, I would like to find all DefaultTasks in TableB that have the same TaskGroup, and then insert those DefaultTasks & the ProjectID as new records in Table C

Comment: in your code you try to insert data from B into c, without explaining which rows fromB you want and what the have to do with A. This makes no sense at all. Which rows you want to insert/Update from B and how fits A into it

Comment: I made some changes to hopefully address your question:
Table A includes the fields ProjectID | TaskGroup.

Table B includes the fields ID |  DefaultTask | TaskGroup.

Table C includes the fields ID |  ProjectID | DefaultTask.

When a new ProjectID & TaskGroup are added to table A, I would like to find all DefaultTasks in TableB that have the same TaskGroup, and then insert those DefaultTasks & the ProjectID as new records in Table C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After You e explanation in the comment.

This shows you how to do it, you Must test  The INSERT Query, it assumes that id is an autoincrement.

Every NEW.columname  is the value of the inserted row.

With INSERT INTO ... SELCT You can male a bulk insert from all Values from Taböleb that fit the bill

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER updateC AFTER Insert ON TableA
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TableC (ProjectID,DefaultTask) SELECT NEW.ProjectID,DefaultTask
                                                    FROM TABLEB 
                                                    WHERE TaskGroup = NEW.TaskGroup;
       END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

FYI: Write sql Comands in UPPER case, it smales the reading much more simple

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The record inserted into `A` must define the record(s) in `B` which must be updated, and the records in `C` which values must be taken for this update.

For example, it may be

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateC 
AFTER INSERT 
ON Table A
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE B, C
SET B.field1 = C.field2
WHERE B.field3 = NEW.field4
  AND C.field5 = NEW.field6;
```